# Binding core plot library in monotouch error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, core-plot, cocoa-bindings

I am using MonoTouch 5.0.2. I am trying to bind the core plot library using **btouch** tool.

First I downloaded core plot library 0.4, then i downloaded the monotouch example which is using this library. Now i have the **coreplot.cs** which is the API definition class and the **enums.cs** class and the **extra.cs** class and finally the **assembly.cs** which link my Objective C library with MonoTouch.

I got this error:

```
Monotouch.coregraphics.cgcolor.handle is inaccessible
monotouch.coregraphics.cgpath.handle is inaccessible
```

My command is:

```
/Developer/Monotouch/usr/bin/btouch coreplot.cs -s: enums.cs extras.cs assemblyInfo.cs --link-with ="libcoreplot-cocatouch.a"
```

Comment: What **exactly** are you using as bindings ? your own ? The latest CorePlot bindings provided on [github][1] were updated on November 4th and were made against CorePlot **0.9** (the main README is out of date, comments in /bindings/ makes it clear that the binding were made for 0.9).


  [1]: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/CorePlot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke btouch with the -e command-line option or 'handle' is private.

You also need to use -x for extras.cs and assemblyinfo.cs (although that is broken up through MonoTouch 5.0.2, so you'll need to wait for 5.0.3 for the following command-line to work):

```
/Developer/Monotouch/usr/bin/btouch -e coreplot.cs -s:enums.cs -x:extras.cs -x:assemblyInfo.cs --link-with ="libcoreplot-cocatouch.a"
```

Alternatively you could use the smcs trick that is used here: http://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/CorePlot

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the .handle to .Handle.

Monotouch SDK follows the .NET naming guidelines and public propertie starts with capital letters. Private or protected variables starts with lower case.

Hope this helps.